# Generic List extension method ForEach stopped working?

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach, generic-list

I have a custom list that inherits Generic.List and it has a method for deselecting all of the members named DeselectAll

It has looked like this for a few weeks and has worked fine.

```
Public Sub DeselectAll()
    MyBase.ForEach(Function(p As Publipostable) p.ModeEnvoiChoisi = Nothing)
End Sub
```

Today, it stopped working ?!? I reverted to an earlier version using delegates and that works fine...

```
Public Sub DeselectAll()
    MyBase.ForEach(AddressOf DeselectModeEnvoi)
End Sub

Private Sub DeselectModeEnvoi(ByVal p As IPublipostable)
    p.ModeEnvoiChoisi = Nothing
End Sub
```

Has anyone seen this behavior? It's in an asp.net 3.5 app.

Just wondering,
Sam

Edit: 
Stopped Working meaning it no longer sets the property p.ModeEnvoiChoisi to Nothing on each item in the list. The DeselectAll method gets called, but all the items retain their previous values...

Comment: `Stopped Working`: A compiler error or just stopped doing anything?

Comment: What changed to make it stop working?

Comment: Note: `ForEach` is an instance method on `List<T>`, not an extension method.

Comment: Can you define "stopped working"?

Comment: I can't believe I asked the question that I detest the most, the generic "doesn't work" question... My bad :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net 3.5 VB doesn't have a way to distinguish between an equality operator vs a set operator since both are "=" and the compiler choses the equality check (weird I know). In .net 4.0 you can use set operators in lambda functions without problems, but in .net 3.5 you can't in VB.

Comment: I'll buy that. But why did it work before? (Or maybe it didn't... damn non-testable code base, arg!)

Comment: I'd go with the second, I had the same exact problem until something expected the for-each to really work and then we were like, what?? Why is that not working! I'm so glad they fixed that in .net 4 though, more sanity, less loss of hair!